# I want to select the text inside input box by clicking on a button in react js but my code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i click on the focus button , i want to change the text inside the input box and then select it.
But  i have to click on the button twice to accomplish this task, that is, when i first click on the button , only the value is changed and when i click again, then the the text is selected

```js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const editItem = () => {
    setName('ray')
    inputRef.current.select();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        value={name}
        placeholder="e.g. eggs"
        onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="button" className="edit-btn" onClick={editItem}>
        Focus
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to trigger the text selection. Toggle a `focus` variable, whenever the focus button is clicked. So, on every click the text gets selected.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.select();
  }, [focus]);
  const editItem = () => {
    setName("ray");
    setFocus(!focus);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        value={name}
        placeholder="e.g. eggs"
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="button" className="edit-btn" onClick={editItem}>
        Focus
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `useEffect` hook to select the text, because state changes in React are asynchronous. Try like this:

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const editItem = () => {
    setName("ray");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (name === "ray") {
      inputRef.current.select();
    }
  }, [name]);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        value={name}
        placeholder="e.g. eggs"
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="button" className="edit-btn" onClick={editItem}>
        Focus
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

The `useEffect` here executes everytime when `name` state is changed and selects the text if it is `ray`, because that's what button click sets it to.

To learn more about `useEffect`, check this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).
Check this code working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-shape-yxz09?file=/src/App.js:0-630).

Answer (score 1):

`setName()` is an asynchronous function which means when you first click the button `inputRef.current.select();` is executed before `setName()` is finished.
As a solution you can do:

```
const editItem = () => {
    setName('ray')
  };

useEffect(()=>
  {
    inputRef.current.select();
  },[name]);
```

This calls `inputRef.current.select()` as soon as `setName()` changes the state.